# Serial port connection handler

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm writing a serial port connection handler for my application, so the user doesn't have to connect to and disconnect from the port himself/herself.  Below you can see the logic and how I plan to maintain the connection.

My problem is that CPU usage skyrockets due to the while loop.  How do I slow down a loop like this without it affecting other parts of the application?

`Thread.Sleep()` is an obvious option.  But are other parts of the application handled by the thread and affected by `Thread.Sleep()` when the connection handler is started by `Task.Run()`?  If so, another option is to start the handler in a separate thread.  But can that cause problems, when the handler is manipulating objects (like the SerialPort object) started up from a different thread?

```
    private void StartConnectionHandler() {
        Task.Run(() => ConnectionHandler());
    }

    private enum ConnectionState {
        AwaitPortSelected,
        IsPortValid,
        OpenPort,
        AwaitLinkStateChange,
        ClosePort
    }

    private void ConnectionHandler() {
        var connectionState = ConnectionState.AwaitPortSelected;
        while (!SerialPortCts.IsCancellationRequested) {
            switch (connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.AwaitPortSelected:
                    break;
                case ConnectionState.IsPortValid:
                    break;
                case ConnectionState.OpenPort:
                    break;
                case ConnectionState.AwaitLinkStateChange:
                    break;
                case ConnectionState.ClosePort:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do need one (or using Timer as @pitersmx suggested) if I want to handle connection to the port automatically (e.g. if user selects a different port to use).  In addition I have an event handler for handling received data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becareful when running `long running work` in `Task.Run()`. When you do `Task.Run()`, by default it execute on a `thread` managed by the default `threadpool`.

If you do an infinite `while` loop with `thread.sleep(1)`, you are essentially blocking one thread of the pool. Assuming you are running with 8 logical cores, you will end up with only 7 available since you are blocking one of the thread forever. For more reading, on why this is bad. This is [a good read regarding jamming the threadpool.](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/03/beware-jamming-thread-pool.html)

A better implementation would be:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConnectionHandler(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

private void ConnectionHandler() {
        var connectionState = ConnectionState.AwaitPortSelected;
        while (!SerialPortCts.IsCancellationRequested) {
            switch (connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.AwaitPortSelected:
                    break;
                case ConnectionState.IsPortValid:
                    break;
                case ConnectionState.OpenPort:
                    break;
                case ConnectionState.AwaitLinkStateChange:
                    break;
                case ConnectionState.ClosePort:
                    break;

                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

By using `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. This would run your work in a dedicated thread that is not managed by the threadpool. In this case, you are safe to block the thread running `ConnectionHandler()`.

*Ideally, to prevent polling like this, an event-based `connectionstate` notification approach would be the best approach, but i am not sure if the api/sdk you are using provided such facilities.*

Comment: Thanks for the help, and link to info on threadpools.  I'm looking into it now.  But how will creating a new thread outside the default threadpool affect interaction with other objects in the application, e.g. the SerialPort object, VM's etc?  Also, the TaskCreationsOption data type should be TaskCreationOptions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `Timer` instead? You can then use its `Tick` event handler and do your stuff periodically on every `Tick` inside it.

```
Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
// Register the tick event handler
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventHandler);

// Configure timer's tick interval (in ms)
myTimer.Interval = 100;
// Run the timer
myTimer.Start();

// Event handler
private static void TimerEventHandler(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs) 
{      
        switch (connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.AwaitPortSelected:
                break;
            case ConnectionState.IsPortValid:
                break;
            case ConnectionState.OpenPort:
                break;
            case ConnectionState.AwaitLinkStateChange:
                break;
            case ConnectionState.ClosePort:
                break;
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for a good tip!  I think I'll leave it as a Task.Run() for now, but I'll keep your idea in mind.